# Virtualbox: cannot start or recover saved machine

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running Virtualbox 5.1.14 r112924 on a Windows 7 Professional machine. I have installed a Debian Testing guest. Several days ago I tried to save the machine, unfortunately I do not recall the exact circumstances, but I think it had to do with the guest having no network any more after the host came back from suspend-to-RAM.

Anyway, I now have a saved machine with which I cannot do anything: I cannot start it, I cannot delete the saved state, I cannnot clone it and I cannot even delete the entire machine. All these options are greyed out in the VB Manager window. Also, I don't get any errors, so I'm rather clueless what to do.

I include below parts of the most recent log file which I thought are relevant, I didn't want to paste the whole thing.

What sort of witchcraft can bring my machine back to life?

Many thanks, and best regards,

Enno

```
02:37:32.316550 Changing the VM state from 'RUNNING' to 'SUSPENDING'
02:37:32.319680 AIOMgr: Endpoint for file 'D:\Users\EnnoMiddelberg\VirtualBox VMs\Debian_Testing\Debian_Testing.vdi' (flags 000c0781) created successfully
02:38:32.373466 PDMR3Suspend: 60 056 883 803 ns run time
02:38:32.373494 Changing the VM state from 'SUSPENDING' to 'SUSPENDED'
02:38:32.373520 Console: Machine state changed to 'Paused'
02:38:32.373700 VMR3Suspend:
02:38:32.393131  RUNNING -> SUSPENDING, RUNNING_LS -> SUSPENDING_EXT_LS failed, because the VM state is actually SUSPENDED
02:38:32.393177 VMSetError: F:\tinderbox\win-5.1\src\VBox\VMM\VMMR3\VM.cpp(3619) int __cdecl vmR3TrySetState(struct VM *,const char *,unsigned int,...); rc=VERR_VM_INVALID_VM_STATE
02:38:32.452926 VMSetError: VMR3Suspend failed because the current VM state, SUSPENDED, was not found in the state transition table (old state RUNNING_LS)
02:38:32.501235 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_VM_ERROR (0x80bb0003) aIID={872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed} aComponent={ConsoleWrap} aText={Could not suspend the machine execution (VERR_VM_INVALID_VM_STATE)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
02:38:32.605107 Console: Machine state changed to 'Saving'
02:38:32.635604 Changing the VM state from 'SUSPENDED' to 'SAVING'
02:38:32.747945 VUSB: Detached 'HidMouse' from port 1
02:38:40.213749 SSM: Footer at 0x23d179e4 (600930788), 34 directory entries.
02:38:40.213777 VUSB: Attached 'HidMouse' to port 1
02:38:40.231560 SSM: Successfully saved the VM state to 'D:\Users\EnnoMiddelberg\VirtualBox VMs\Debian_Testing\Snapshots\2017-05-23T14-48-18-411341300Z.sav'
02:38:40.231578 Changing the VM state from 'SAVING' to 'SUSPENDED'
02:38:40.316839 Console::powerDown(): A request to power off the VM has been issued (mMachineState=Saving, InUninit=0)
02:38:40.342613 Display::handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=000000000c0a0000 w=1920 h=1106 bpp=32 cbLine=0x1E00 flags=0x1
02:38:40.342664 GUI: UIFrameBufferPrivate::NotifyChange: Screen=0, Origin=0x0, Size=1920x1106, Sending to async-handler
02:38:40.350656 Changing the VM state from 'SUSPENDED' to 'POWERING_OFF'
02:38:40.356473 ****************** Guest state at power off for VCpu 0 ******************
...
...
...
02:38:40.406031 ************** End of Guest state at power off ***************
02:38:41.753488 PDMR3PowerOff: Driver 'AUDIO'/0 on LUN#0 of device 'ichac97'/0 took 1 344 979 632 ns to power off
02:38:41.753791 PDMR3PowerOff: 1 347 726 353 ns run time
02:38:41.762544 Changing the VM state from 'POWERING_OFF' to 'OFF'
02:38:41.983956 Changing the VM state from 'OFF' to 'DESTROYING'
02:38:41.984097 ************************* Statistics *************************
...
...
...
02:38:41.990221 ********************* End of statistics **********************
02:38:41.997747 VUSB: Detached 'HidMouse' from port 1
02:38:42.377555 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_cluster, used:90)
02:38:42.378711 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_packet, used:90)
02:38:42.378737 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf, used:90)
02:38:42.378763 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_pagesize, used:0)
02:38:42.379768 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_9k, used:0)
02:38:42.380260 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_16k, used:0)
02:38:42.380639 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_ext_refcnt, used:0)
02:39:42.706185 GIM: KVM: Resetting MSRs
02:39:42.720224 Changing the VM state from 'DESTROYING' to 'TERMINATED'
02:39:42.723143 Console: Machine state changed to 'Saved'
02:39:42.723504 GUI: Request to close Runtime UI because VM is powered off already.
02:39:42.888614 GUI: Passing request to close Runtime UI from machine-logic to UI session.
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I got the machine back up by removing the *.sav file in the guest's "Snapshots" subdirectory. It had to sort out its file system when booting, but everything is running as it should now.

Thanks for listening, anyway...